# effect estimate without constant variance (r sandwich vcovHC)

Tags: r, sandwich

For the sandwich package in R, when using `vcovHC(model)` where `model <- lm(Y~X)`, what gives the effect estimate regarding the relationship between X and Y (for each unit change in X, Y will change ....)?

Is it still the estimate of the X coefficient given by `summary(model)`? Or is it now the covariance of the two model parameters given by `vcovHC(model)`? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 3):

When using the sandwich standard error, the association between $X$ and $Y$ is no different than in the `model`: the regression slope, or "X" coefficient is the same as is obtained by `coef(model)`. What `vcovHC` does differently is calculate the standard errors for the confidence interval and the p-value of the model.

If you would like to see output similar to `summary(model)` but using sandwich errors, you can make use of the `lmtest` package and function `parmtest` by calling:

`parmtest(model, .vcov=vcovHC)`

and contrast these findings with the model based summary: `summary(model)`.